# Updating a ComboBox SelectedItem from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

im having a View with a ComboBox bound to my viewModel property. 
Everything works fine but i actually want to reuse my View and need to 
update the controls with a given value. Setting the property wont update the visual UI 
even to event is fired and everyting looks good.

Everything works accept the ComboBox visual UI.

Tips?!

XAML control

```
<telerik:RadComboBox 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectUserComboBoxTemplate}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=C_users}" 
            telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="displayName"
            Name="radComboBox1" 
            Margin="14,12,0,0" 
            Height="31" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Width="253" 
            TextSearchMode="Contains"
            IsEditable="True"
            OpenDropDownOnFocus="True" 
            IsFilteringEnabled="True"
            >
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

The overloaded constructor that sets the values

```
    public TicketControlTabViewModel(ticket t)
    {
        activeTicket = t;
        SelectedUser = customerServiceClient.getUser(t.customer_users.id);
        MetaString = t.meta;
        Description = t.description;
        ActiveId = t.id.ToString();
        Selected_priority = t.priority;
        SelectedStatus = t.status;
        this.RefreshC_users();
        this.RefreshSupportDepartments();
        this.RefreshSupportUsers();
    }
```

The property in my ViewModel

```
    private customer_users selectedUser { get; set; }
    public customer_users SelectedUser
    {

        get {
            return this.selectedUser;
            }
        set {
              if (value != null){
              this.selectedUser = value;
              this.UpdateCustomerDepartment(value);
              this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
              SaveTicket();
              }

            }
    }
```

Comment: @Bolt you edited, but left that tag in the title?  Sheesh.

Comment: Is C_users an ObservableCollection?

Comment: private IEnumerable<customer_users> c_users;
        public IEnumerable<customer_users> C_users
        {
            get
            {
                
                return this.c_users;
            }
            set
            {
                this.c_users = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("C_users");
               
            }
        }

Comment: But the control should react to the SelectedUser.... the itemsource works... i can still choose users and they get selected and so on. Its just to update the actual controll with the pre selected item .... i think its since the control is time loaded issue....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, WPF compares the `SelectedItem` by reference, not by value. That means if the `SelectedItem` isn't the exact same object in memory as the item in your `ItemsSource`, then the comparisom will return false and the item will not get selected.

For example, this will probably not work

```
MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>(DAL.GetUsers());
SelectedUser = DAL.GetUser(1);
```

however this would:

```
MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>(DAL.GetUsers());
SelectedUser = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
```

That's because the 2nd example sets the SelectedUser to an item that actually exists in `MyCollection`, while the 1st example might not. Even if the data is the same, they reference different objects in memory.

If your selected item doesn't reference the same item in memory as your ItemsSource item, then either use `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` to bind your ComboBox's default selection, or overwrite the `.Equals()` method of your class to return true if the data in the objects being compared is the same.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || !(obj == MyClass))
        return false; 

    return ((MyClass)obj).Id == this.Id);
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much I just wasted most of a day trying to figure this out. I used your LINQ example and added a new property to bind the ComboBox SelectedItem to which then used LINQ to select and return the actual item by reference.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen if you do not `Items` collection doesn't contain an item equal to `SelectedItem`. Check whether you have such an item (it may be that you just forgot to overload `Equals` in your class and it uses references comparison)

Comment: The items objects comes from my Entity Model... (or the info)

Comment: Loaded the viewModel after the controls and vice versa and its still the same so such an easy fix was to hope for the best  :)

Comment: Your on to something Snowbear.... reading in the forums 
""i implemented Equals and GetHashCode on the field class
and it worked"" but is it on my user items? 

Wanna be sure before i work more with it since its from a entity its a kinda hassle...

Comment: yes, `customer_users` should implement it. Otherwise it will work only if you set `SelectedItem` same as one of the items in your collection.  Same in terms of default **equals** implementation

Comment: You where correct Snowbear! 
Added a Equals override and voila!